# (Not) Adding NuGet packages to GIT on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, visual-studio-2012

Having worked with `composer`, `npm` and different others, developers don't upload dependencies nor binary files to source control. That being said, as my first time working with NuGet packages, I noticed they are being included by default (**dlls** and **exes**).

So either there is no command relative to `npm install` that will download every dependency listed on a file and I have to upload dlls and exe to source control, or this is done by default by visual studio as a mistake. Which one is it? 
If it does have a way to restore package, which one it is?

PS: I haven't made the first commit yet; waiting to exclude/untrack anything that doesn't need to be on source control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you do not put NuGet packages in the source control. There is an option to allow NuGet to restore required packages as a part of the build process. Also you can restore those packages manually from the command line or from the UI, similar to npm.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I needed. Can you show how set up VS to restore NuGet package on build?

Comment: in the solution explorer, right click on References, select Manage NuGet packages. Click on the Settings button bottom left. The from the General tab check Allow NuGet to restore packages...